# Using conditional Sub-Arrays using VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I would like to know how to use Vuejs to output a conditional sublist. In this example, not all topics have a subtopic.

```
new Vue ({
    el: '#maincontainer',
    data: {
        topics: [
            { topicname: 'Introduction' },
            { topicname: 'First Chapter', 
                subtopics: [
                    {subtopicname: 'Test'}
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
});
```

My HTML so far looks like this:

```
<li v-for="topic in topics" id="item-{{$index}}">
    {{ topic.topicname }} 
     <ul>
       <li v-for="subtopic in subtopics">
         {{ subtopic.subtopicname }}
       </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

How might I have the list optionally add a sublist if there is one in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) is the directive to be used for conditional rendering.

Here you could use `v-if='topic.subtopic'` too (as long as the value of the expression evaluates to a truthy boolean value if `subtopic` existed.)

```
<li v-for="topic in topics" id="item-{{$index}}">
{{ topic.topicname }} 
   <ul v-if='Array.isArray(topic.subtopic)'>
     <li v-for="subtopic in topic.subtopics">
       {{ subtopic.subtopicname }}
     </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
```

You might also be interested in [`v-else`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else)